# How I can send data to ble device in background service of android?

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send string value period to BLE device in background service of android.
- Scan device
- Scan service
- Write data to BLE device

Does anyone know best algorithm to implement period sending in background service of android?

Comment: there is no best. Have you tried doing it? which problems you faced?

Comment: Everything you need is available in open source projects. For example the RxAndroidBle project has an example program which does all of the BLE behavior you asked for. All you will need to do is copy the code and add a timer to write periodically.